# Remove default option onChange event of selected select element?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors, html-select

I have two HTML select elements on a form. In the current setup the *default option* for both selects is read in from the database.

When the selected item changes in a select I want to remove the default option from that select element not others.

The issue at the moment is that, when I change the selected item in one Select, the default option is removed from **both** Selects. Where it should only be removed from the control that fires the change event.

I did try also using `$('option:selected', this).remove();` on each independent change event. But this code removes an item from the select on every change. Where as the use case requires only removing the default option.

How can you remove the default option of only the *selected* select element?

So in the markup I defined two select elements with ID's `EventName` and `Status`:

```
                                <!-- SELECT STATUS STATIC-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-9 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="Current Status">Current Status</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <select id="Status" name="Status" style="width:165px;" class="btn btn-default">
                                            @foreach (Models.RecStatus status in Model.Status)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@status.RecStatus">@status.RecStatus</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <!-- SELECT EVENT STATIC-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-9 control-label" style="text-align: left;" for="Event">Event</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <select id="EventName" name="EventName" style="width:165px;" class="btn btn-default">
                                            @foreach (Models.RecEvent eventType in Model.Event)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@eventType.EventType">@eventType.EventType</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>  


//Remove the extra default Event and Status select elements
//onChange
$('#EventName').on('change', function() {
    //$('option:selected', this).remove();
    $("#defaultOption").remove();
});



$('#Status').on('change', function() {
    //$('option:selected', this).remove();
    $("#defaultOption").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could remove them based on their value

```
$('#EventName').one('change', function() {
    $(this).find("option[value='']").remove();
}
```

or you could remove the last option

```
$('#EventName').one('change', function() {
    $(this).find('option:last').remove();
}
```

Comment: The default value varies by record, so I can't remove based on value in this case.

Comment: are they always going to be the 1st `<option>`? See my edit

Comment: Default option is always going to the last item in the select list and set to default. I only want to remove the default last option on the first change event. 


Subsequent change events shouldn't remove anything from the select's list.

Comment: ah, okay.. hang tight

Comment: take a look at my edit, I changed `first` to `last` and `.on()` to `.one()`, which will only bind the event once, after the first change it will unbind

Comment: Ok the `.one('change'` is the key here. Works only on the first change event now.